# Append parent to xml

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I want to add one more block to xml file. Basicly under parent `Tss` I want to create sublement `Entry` with its attributes. Here is what I want to add to xml file:

```
         <Entry>
            <System string = "rbs005019"/>
            <Type string = "SECURE"/>
            <User string = "rbs"/>
            <Password string = "rbs005019"/>
        </Entry>
```

and here is the xml file

```
   <ManagedElement sourceType = "CELLO">
        <ManagedElementId string = "rbs005019"/>
        <Tss>
            <Entry>
                <System string = "rbs005019"/>
                <Type string = "NORMAL"/>
                <User string = "rbs"/>
                <Password string = "rbs005019"/>
            </Entry>
        </Tss>
    </ManagedElement>
```

so after combing it should look like:

```
  <ManagedElement sourceType = "CELLO">
        <ManagedElementId string = "rbs005019"/>
        <Tss>
            <Entry>
                <System string = "rbs005019"/>
                <Type string = "NORMAL"/>
                <User string = "rbs"/>
                <Password string = "rbs005019"/>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <System string = "rbs005019"/>
                <Type string = "SECURE"/>
                <User string = "rbs"/>
                <Password string = "rbs005019"/>
            </Entry>
        </Tss>
        </ManagedElement>
```

I'm using python 2.6 and `lxml.etree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lxml has the function `parentElem.insert(position, new_element)` that allows you to insert a new child element under its parent. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909647/lxml-insert-tag-at-a-given-position) and [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) (Section *Elements are lists*)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using insert:

```
In [31]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:current = """ <ManagedElement sourceType = "CELLO">
:        <ManagedElementId string = "rbs005019"/>
:        <Tss>
:            <Entry>
:                <System string = "rbs005019"/>
:                <Type string = "NORMAL"/>
:                <User string = "rbs"/>
:                <Password string = "rbs005019"/>
:            </Entry>
:        </Tss>
:    </ManagedElement>
:"""
:<EOF>

In [32]: current = etree.fromstring(current)

In [33]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:want = """
: <Entry>
:            <System string = "rbs005019"/>
:            <Type string = "SECURE"/>
:            <User string = "rbs"/>
:            <Password string = "rbs005019"/>
:        </Entry>
:"""
:<EOF>

In [34]: want = etree.fromstring(want)

In [35]: current.find('./Tss').insert(0,want)

In [36]: print etree.tostring(current, pretty_print=True)
<ManagedElement sourceType="CELLO">
        <ManagedElementId string="rbs005019"/>
        <Tss>
            <Entry>
            <System string="rbs005019"/>
            <Type string="SECURE"/>
            <User string="rbs"/>
            <Password string="rbs005019"/>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <System string="rbs005019"/>
            <Type string="NORMAL"/>
            <User string="rbs"/>
            <Password string="rbs005019"/>
        </Entry>
       </Tss>
    </ManagedElement>
```

The insert happens with this line:
`current.find('./Tss').insert(0,want)`