# Parent node insertion in XML in Python not working like I wished

Tags: python, xml, tags, lxml, elementtree

I have a long XML file structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="192.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="193.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Attribute "bbox" contains four values, and I want to insert the tag "newline" every time there is a certain distance between the first number of the coordinates (example here, in the file they are all different) provided.

The concept is that if the distance between the first number of the current bbox and its preceding one is > 10, insert an open `<newline>` tag and close it when the distance comes again (in other words, close the tag when there is the need to open a new one). So the output would be:

```
<newline>[text tags]</newline>
<newline>[text tags]</newline>
```

etc.

My code so far is this:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.builder import E

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('fe2.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()

def removeByIdx(parent, idx):
    currElem = parent[idx]   # The indicated element
    parent.remove(currElem)  # Remove it from the parent
    return currElem          # Return the index and element

def wrap(line, idxList):
    if len(idxList) == 0:
        return    # No elements to wrap
    # Take the first element from the original location
    idx = idxList.pop(0)     # Index of the first element
    elem = removeByIdx(line, idx) # The indicated element
    # Create "newline" element with "elem" inside
    nElem = E.newline(elem)
    line.insert(idx, nElem)  # Put it in place of "elem"
    while len(idxList) > 0:  # Process the rest of index list
        # Value not used, but must be removed
        idxList.pop(0)
        # Remove the current element from the original location
        currElem = removeByIdx(line, idx + 1)
        nElem.append(currElem)  # Append it to "newline"

for line in root.iter('textline'):
    idxList = []
    for x in line:
        bb = x.attrib.get('bbox')
        if bb is not None:
            bb = bb.split(',')
        #print('This: ', bb)
        this = bb
        xPrev = x.getprevious()
        bb = None
        if xPrev is not None:
            bb = xPrev.attrib.get('bbox')
            if bb is not None:
                bb = bb.split(',')
        if bb is not None:
            prev = bb
            #print(this, prev)
            if this is not None:
                distance = float(this[0]) - float(prev[0])
                print(distance)
                if distance > 10:
                    par = x.getparent()
                    idx = par.index(x)
                    idxList.append(idx)
                else:  # "Wrong" element, wrap elements "gathered" so far
                    wrap(line, idxList)
                    idxList = []
                    # Process "good" elements without any "bad" after them, if any
                wrap(line, idxList)


print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

But it doesn't work as expected, I see no newline tag and if I shorten the distance it just wraps one text element. What am I missing?

EDIT: expected output

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="199.227,592.218,205.657,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="205.545,592.218,211.975,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="211.023,592.218,218.617,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="218.515,592.218,226.109,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">R</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="226.008,592.218,233.602,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="232.812,592.218,240.932,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">T</text>O


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,554.008,49.369,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,554.008,54.022,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>a


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,475.008,48.317,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,475.008,52.980,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>b


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,421.608,49.369,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,421.608,54.022,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>c


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,339.508,48.317,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,339.508,52.980,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>d


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.949,237.108,49.703,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.274,237.108,54.028,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">5</text>a

    **<newline>**
    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="68.031,553.639,76.375,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">T</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="76.231,553.639,79.479,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">i</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="79.334,553.639,83.161,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">t</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="83.017,553.639,88.112,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="87.968,553.639,91.216,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">l</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="91.071,553.639,96.167,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
 <whitespace/><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="99.311,553.628,104.406,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="104.261,553.628,107.510,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">l</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="107.365,553.628,110.269,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text>
 <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="110.658,553.628,119.002,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="118.857,553.628,123.953,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">a</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="123.808,553.628,130.183,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">u</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="130.038,553.628,134.555,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">s</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="134.410,553.628,137.659,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="137.514,553.628,143.889,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="143.744,553.628,146.993,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="146.848,553.628,151.943,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">c</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="151.799,553.628,157.595,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="157.450,553.628,161.277,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">]</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="161.132,553.628,164.036,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text>
 <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="164.417,553.639,168.244,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="168.099,553.639,173.895,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">p</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="173.751,553.639,177.578,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="176.966,553.639,180.215,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">.</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="180.070,553.639,182.974,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727"> </text>
 <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="183.363,553.639,189.159,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">a</text>
 <whitespace/><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="192.314,553.628,201.937,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">D</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="201.793,553.628,207.589,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="207.444,553.628,213.819,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">n</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="213.674,553.628,216.578,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text> <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="216.967,553.628,225.311,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">R</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="225.166,553.628,230.962,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="230.818,553.628,237.192,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="237.048,553.628,241.565,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">r</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="241.420,553.628,244.668,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="244.524,553.628,250.320,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">g</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="250.064,553.628,255.860,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text> <text>
    </text>
    **</newline>**
    **<newline>**
    <text font="QKWQNQ+ImprintMTnum-Bold" bbox="272.661,554.072,277.415,564.757" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.685">1</text>
    ... continues
**</newline>**
```

Comment: Please, can you share the expected output ?

Comment: Yes, I put an edit to my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Does the `<whitespace>` and empty `text` element needs te be kept ?

Comment: They do, but if they can be replaced it's okay as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

1. Find the `text` elements using [`xpath`](https://lxml.de/1.3/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method)
2. Iterate over all elements:

   - For all items, we keep the current value and previous values from the BBox. We keep the last valid value. That means that, if for a given element, the `bbox` tag is missing, the previous one will be used.
   - Then we compute distance (e.g. `|bb_current` - `bb_previous|`)
   - If the distance is bigger than 10: that means a new `new_line` tag needs to be opened. But first, we need to close the previous one. So the `current_line` is inserted in parent tag using `insert` ([related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909647/lxml-insert-tag-at-a-given-position/15918818))
   - If the `new_line` is already open: we add current tags inside using `append`, else we let them as original.
3. Finally, we add the last `new_line` element outside the loop.

**Notes**: the others tag such as empty `text` elements or `whitespace` elemnts are move. They need to be handle in for loop if we want to keep their origin position.

**Full code**:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('data.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()

# Get the first BBox value as float
# Return null if not found
def getBBoxFirstValue(line):
    if line is not None:
        bb = line.attrib.get('bbox')
        if bb is not None:
            try:
                return float(bb.split(",")[0])
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return None


new_line        = None 
previous_bb     = None

for x in tree.xpath('//text'):
    # Get current bb value
    bb = getBBoxFirstValue(x)

    # Check current and past values aren't empty
    if bb is not None and previous_bb is not None:
        # If distance with preview bb > 10
        if abs(bb - previous_bb) > 10:
            # If new_line isn't empty: it's inserted into parent tag at position of current tag 
            if new_line is not None:
                x.getparent().insert(x.getparent().index(x), new_line)
            # A new "new_line" element is created
            new_line = etree.Element("new_line")

        # If the new line isn't not (e.g. one distance > 10 has been already found)
        if new_line is not None:
            new_line.append(x)

    # Keep latest non empty BBox 1st value
    if bb is not None:
        previous_bb = bb


# Add last new_line element if not null
if new_line is not None:
    tree.xpath('//text')[-1].getparent().append(new_line)


newtree = etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
newtree = newtree.decode("utf-8")
```

---

*input.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="199.227,592.218,205.657,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="205.545,592.218,211.975,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="211.023,592.218,218.617,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="218.515,592.218,226.109,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">R</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="226.008,592.218,233.602,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="232.812,592.218,240.932,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">T</text>
                O
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,554.008,49.369,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,554.008,54.022,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>
                a
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,475.008,48.317,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,475.008,52.980,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>
                b
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,421.608,49.369,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,421.608,54.022,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>
                c
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,339.508,48.317,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,339.508,52.980,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>
                d
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.949,237.108,49.703,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.274,237.108,54.028,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">5</text>
                a
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="68.031,553.639,76.375,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">T</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="76.231,553.639,79.479,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">i</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="79.334,553.639,83.161,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">t</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="83.017,553.639,88.112,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="87.968,553.639,91.216,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">l</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="91.071,553.639,96.167,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="99.311,553.628,104.406,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="104.261,553.628,107.510,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">l</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="107.365,553.628,110.269,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="110.658,553.628,119.002,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="118.857,553.628,123.953,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">a</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="123.808,553.628,130.183,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">u</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="130.038,553.628,134.555,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">s</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="134.410,553.628,137.659,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="137.514,553.628,143.889,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="143.744,553.628,146.993,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="146.848,553.628,151.943,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">c</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="151.799,553.628,157.595,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="157.450,553.628,161.277,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">]</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="161.132,553.628,164.036,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"></text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="164.417,553.639,168.244,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="168.099,553.639,173.895,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">p</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="173.751,553.639,177.578,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="176.966,553.639,180.215,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">.</text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="180.070,553.639,182.974,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727"></text>
                <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="183.363,553.639,189.159,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">a</text>
                <whitespace/>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="192.314,553.628,201.937,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">D</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="201.793,553.628,207.589,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="207.444,553.628,213.819,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">n</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="213.674,553.628,216.578,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="216.967,553.628,225.311,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">R</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="225.166,553.628,230.962,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="230.818,553.628,237.192,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="237.048,553.628,241.565,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">r</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="241.420,553.628,244.668,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="244.524,553.628,250.320,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">g</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="250.064,553.628,255.860,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="QKWQNQ+ImprintMTnum-Bold" bbox="272.661,554.072,277.415,564.757" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.685">1</text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

*output*

```
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="199.227,592.218,205.657,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="205.545,592.218,211.975,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="211.023,592.218,218.617,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="218.515,592.218,226.109,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">R</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="226.008,592.218,233.602,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="232.812,592.218,240.932,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">T</text>
                O
                <new_line>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,554.008,49.369,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,554.008,54.022,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>        
                a
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,475.008,48.317,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,475.008,52.980,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>        
                b
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,421.608,49.369,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,421.608,54.022,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>        
                c
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,339.508,48.317,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,339.508,52.980,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>        
                d
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.949,237.108,49.703,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.274,237.108,54.028,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">5</text>        
                a
                </new_line>
                <whitespace/>
                <text/>
                <new_line>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="68.031,553.639,76.375,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">T</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="76.231,553.639,79.479,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">i</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="79.334,553.639,83.161,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">t</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="83.017,553.639,88.112,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="87.968,553.639,91.216,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">l</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="91.071,553.639,96.167,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="99.311,553.628,104.406,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="104.261,553.628,107.510,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">l</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="107.365,553.628,110.269,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"/>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="110.658,553.628,119.002,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="118.857,553.628,123.953,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">a</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="123.808,553.628,130.183,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">u</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="130.038,553.628,134.555,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">s</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="134.410,553.628,137.659,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="137.514,553.628,143.889,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="143.744,553.628,146.993,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="146.848,553.628,151.943,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">c</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="151.799,553.628,157.595,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="157.450,553.628,161.277,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">]</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="161.132,553.628,164.036,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"/>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="164.417,553.639,168.244,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="168.099,553.639,173.895,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">p</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="173.751,553.639,177.578,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="176.966,553.639,180.215,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">.</text>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="180.070,553.639,182.974,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727"/>
                    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="183.363,553.639,189.159,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">a</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="192.314,553.628,201.937,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">D</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="201.793,553.628,207.589,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="207.444,553.628,213.819,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">n</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="213.674,553.628,216.578,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"/>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="216.967,553.628,225.311,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">R</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="225.166,553.628,230.962,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="230.818,553.628,237.192,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="237.048,553.628,241.565,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">r</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="241.420,553.628,244.668,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="244.524,553.628,250.320,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">g</text>
                    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="250.064,553.628,255.860,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
                </new_line>
                <new_line>
                    <text font="QKWQNQ+ImprintMTnum-Bold" bbox="272.661,554.072,277.415,564.757" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.685">1</text>
                </new_line>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: thank you!! I get this error:  File "C:/Users/annas/PycharmProjects/TESI/oooooo.py", line 36, in <module>
    parent.insert(parent.index(x), new_line)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1216, in lxml.etree._Element.index
ValueError: Element is not a child of this node. ; do you have any idea why?

Comment: Does this problem occurs on the example I provided or another `xml` file ? If yes, can you update it in the question ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand it better and basically the problem seems to be that since my XML is longer (it repeats pages and everything inside them), somehow the code doesn't work but works with the short input

Comment: would it be useful to put a link to the full XML I'm using?

Comment: Does the `<text>...</text>` elements all belong to the same parent ? Yes sure !

Comment: It should be visible: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dersuchendee/TESI/master/fe2.xml I think they don't belong to the same parent, or better to the same parent tag yes but maybe another iteration it's needed?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the current solution. Does the distance must be computed within a parent tag or it could use `<text>` tag whatever the parent ?

Comment: The distance uses the <text> tag whatever the parent!