# Python / XML: Finding index of elements using iter

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm hoping to find the index of elements in some xml so I can insert after them using index + 1.

I'm currently using elementtree.

The documentation makes reference to addressing nodes by location, and inserting at an index position. I'd like to discover the index position of the last `<Weather>` element.

Sample code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """<parentelem>
    <Weather>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Stream 1</name>
    </Weather>
    <Weather>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Stream 2</name>
    </Weather>
    <Setting>
        <my_setting>True</my_setting>
    </Setting>
</parentelem>"""

xml_obj = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

a_lst = list(root.iter('Weather'))
        print(a_lst) 
        #[<Element 'Weather' at 0x00000211B1F18D60>, <Element 'Weather' at 0x00000211B1F1F2C0>]

        for a in a_lst:
            print(a.index())
            #AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I've also tried to use variants of these:

```
print(root.find('Weather[last()]').position)
print(root.find('Weather[last()]').index)
```

I'm struggling to discover how to get the positional index of an element, but figure it must be possible since we can query the content based on location/index, and also insert based on location/index.

The expected output is a number, or an array containing numbers. The last `<Weather` tag is in position `[3]`

Comment: There are only two `Weather` elements.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that, sorry. Ultimately I'll have hundreds or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
root.find('.//Weather[last()]/name').text
```

Or try it with lxml which better supports xpath:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(xml_string)
#for example:
print(doc.xpath('//Weather[last()]/name/text()'))
```

Output:

```
['Stream 2']
```

To find the position of the last element (using lxml):

```
doc.xpath('count(//Weather[last()]/preceding-sibling::*)')+1
```

Output:

```
2.0
```

Comment: I'm going to have to reimplement a few things in my script to use lxml, which is ok. That probably does change how I need to implement the next component, however, which is assentially going to be an insert-after the last record of interest type of scenario. Can the statement you shared above return a position= eg this ```<Weather>``` is an object at index location 3?

Comment: Looks like addnext() is going to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909647/lxml-insert-tag-at-a-given-position/15918818

Comment: @anakaine To your first comment - yes; see edit.